# spark streaming not executing spark sql query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am facing one issue during executing spark sql on top of spark streaming.

i am not getting printed the value of x on the line    var x = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from prices")

please find my code here below

```
    import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import java.util.regex.Pattern
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("streamHive").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))    
val sc=ssc.sparkContext

val lines = ssc.textFileStream("file:///home/sdf/testHive")
case class Prices(name: String, age: String,sex: String, location: String)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

def parse (rdd : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] ) = {
var l = rdd.map(_.split(","))
val prices = l.map(p => Prices(p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3)))
val pricesDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(prices)
pricesDf.registerTempTable("prices")
println("showing printdfShow")
pricesDf.show()
var x = sqlContext.sql("select count(*) from prices")
println("hello")
println (x)
}

lines.foreachRDD { rdd => parse(rdd)}

ssc.start()
```

I am getting following result, its not printing spark sql result:

```
   [count(1): bigint]
   showing printdfShow
   +----+---+---+--------+
   |name|age|sex|location|
   +----+---+---+--------+
   +----+---+---+--------+

   hello
   [count(1): bigint]
   showing printdfShow
   +----+---+---+--------+
   |name|age|sex|location|
   +----+---+---+--------+
   | rop| 22|  M|      uk|
   | fop| 24|  F|      us|
   | dop| 23|  M|     fok|
   +----+---+---+--------+

   hello
   [count(1): bigint]
   showing printdfShow
   +----+---+---+--------+
   |name|age|sex|location|
   +----+---+---+--------+
   +----+---+---+--------+

   hello
   [count(1): bigint]
```

please help me , how to use spark sql in spark streaming as i am new to spark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spark streaming not able to use spark sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872626/spark-streaming-not-able-to-use-spark-sql)

Comment: scenario is different

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your code after pricesDf.show

```
println(pricesDf.count)
```

If you want this in the same code then try the below , not println(x)

```
x.show
```

x is a dataframe not a value thats why its not getting printed while you are running println(x). To get it in a variable you can try this

```
println(x.rdd.map(r => r.getString(0)).collect()(0))
```